# How to store array with array_push() outside loop?

Tags: php, jquery, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array, when i tried to print_r was just like this :

```
Array ( [user_id] => Erick ) Array ( [user_id] => Baldi) Array([user_id]=> Bintang ) Array ( [user_id] => Bagas ) Array ( [user_id] => Baim )
```

My Expected output just like :

```
Array (
    Array ( 
        [user_id] => Erick 
    ) 
    Array ( 
        [user_id] => Baldi
    ) 
    Array ( 
        [user_id] => Bintang 
    ) 
    Array ( 
        [user_id] => Bagas 
    ) 
    Array ( 
        [user_id] => Baim 
    )
)
```

Anyone here have an idea ? I'm stuck with this. 
This my php code :

```
public function get_userid() {
    // $action  = $this->input->post('action');
    $customerField  = $this->input->post('customer');
    $projectField   = $this->input->post('project');
    $user_roleField = $this->input->post('role');

    for ($i=0; $i<count($customerField); $i++) { 
        for ($j=0; $j<count($projectField); $j++) { 
            for ($k=0; $k<count($user_roleField); $k++) { 
                array_push($test, $this->get_array_push($customerField[$i], $projectField[$j], $user_roleField[$k]));
            }
        }
    }   
}

public function get_array_push($customer, $project, $user_role) {

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT user_id
    FROM  `ixt_user_project_list` 
    LEFT JOIN ixt_user_type ON ixt_user_project_list.user_type = ixt_user_type.user_type
    WHERE ixt_user_project_list.user_cust_id ='".$customer."'
    AND ixt_user_project_list.user_project_id ='".$project."'
    AND ixt_user_type.user_owner ='".$user_role."'")->result_array();

    //Filter null array
    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        print_r($value);
    }
}
```

And this is my initial query value :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => Erick ) ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => Baldi ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => Bintang ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => Bagas ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => Baim ) )
```

Comment: You are using print_r inside the foreach  so you see a record  by time  try using print_r outside  the foreach

Comment: i used print_r inside foreach just because i want to print all the userid inside array that was not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @scaisEdge wrote - its happening because you use the `print_r` inside the `foreach` loop.

If you want to filter `null` result you can use [array-filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)  as:

```
$arr = array(array("user_id" => "aaa"), null, array(), array("user_id" => null), array("otherField" => "bbb"));
$filterdResult = array_filter($arr, function($elem) {
    return ($elem && array_key_exists("user_id", $elem) && !is_null($elem["user_id"]));
});
```

Now you can just do `print_r($filterdResult );`

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => aaa
        )
)
```

**Edited:** After setting your new input as:

```
$query = array(array(array("user_id" => "aaa"), null, array(), array("user_id" => null)), array(array("user_id" => "ccc"), null, array(),array("user_id" =>"ddd")));
```

You can use the following:

```
$res = array();
//Filter null array
foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        array_push($res, array_filter($value, function($elem) {
                return ($elem && array_key_exists("user_id", $elem) && !is_null($elem["user_id"])); }));
}
print_r($res);
```

Which output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => aaa
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => ccc
                )
            [3] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => ddd
                )
        )
)
```

From here flatten is available if needed.

Comment: i tried to replace my foreach with your suggesstion, but it still there are empty value inside.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => Erick ) ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => Baldi ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => Bintang ) ) Array ( [0] => Array ( [user_id] => Bagas ) [1] => Array ( [user_id] => Baim ) )

Comment: @aldi weird - in my answer I also add empty array and the filter works fine. I added another way (by using extra array) hope that will help

Comment: the differences in my case is my $query array have dynamic array branch, it shows like these 
$query = array(array("user_id" => "aaa"), null, array(), array("user_id" => null)),
                array(array("user_id" => "ccc"), null, array(),array("user_id" =>"ddd")),

Comment: actually i've find best solutions for my case, i'll still remark your best answer although im not using as your suggesstion. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

@David Winder I tried to combine as your suggesstion with the null array filter.

```
$res = array(); 
    //Filter null array
    foreach ($query as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_null($value)) {
            $res[] = $value;
            //print_r($res);
        }
    }
```

But when i print_r($res) inside the foreach loop the result became duplicate array inside all of the array value.